# What happens after executing the 'python manage.py runserver' command?

Tags: django

I am curious to know what all steps occur at the execution of the 'python manage.py runserver' command.

Comment: Question too broad to answer in a single post. See [this](https://medium.com/@arpitgupta820/what-happens-when-you-hit-runserver-in-django-962a295f06ea) for comprehensive detail on what happens.

Answer (score 2):

```
def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'slambook.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As we can clearly see it imports the `execute_from_command_line` method from `django.core.management` and then calls the function with `sys.argv` as parameter. The parameter `sys.argv` is a list which contains values like location of the directory, the command executed (`runserver` in our case) and the IP address on which the development server is hosted. When we step into that function we see that we create an instance of `ManagementUtitlity` by passing the arguments to its constructor.

```
def execute_from_command_line(argv=None):
    """Run a ManagementUtility."""
    utility = ManagementUtility(argv)
    utility.execute()
```

The constructor takes the program name and other argument but that stuff is not important to us now. The instance is returned and the `instance.execute` method is called.

Inside the execute function the subcommand form the complete command is obtained, that in our case is `runserver`. If no command is given it takes the subcommand as help using the error handling mechanism. Here we instantiate a class called `CommandParser` which extends a class `ArgumentParser` from the builtin library `argparse`. To the people who do not know what `argpase` is, it is python library which is used to build user-friendly command line tools.

To this command parser two arguments are parsed: one is usage whose value is set to `%(prog)s subcommand [options] [args]` and the other is `add_help` which is set to false. When we step into it we see a variable `cmd` which is initialized and remaining keyword arguments are sent to super class constructor. Stepping into it there is a lot going on. Various instance variables are initialized and again super class constructor is called with 4 arguments: `description(none)`, `prefix_chars(‘-’)`, `argument_default(None)`, and `conflict_handler(error)`. We are not going into this as well as this is the implementation of the builtin module `argparse` is beside all the things going on in this module. One thing caught my eye though where they use regular expressions to find if an option looked like a negative number. Parser object is returned and arguments are added to parser. Now there is a check that if the `runserver` command is called with a flag `— noreload`, and if not then there is an interesting line of code:

```
autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
```

The `autoreload` is again a different module in django’s utils as the name itself indicates this has all the functionalities related to the auto reloading feature of `django. autoreloade.check_errors`. It is a decorator which takes in a function and returns a wrapped function which has exceptions handling mechanism which plays the role of displaying the file name whenever an exception occurs. It takes `django.setup` functions and wraps it up and returns. On return the function is called. When stepped in it looks something like this.

So as shown first the logging is configured this according to me is the reason for all the logging messages we see when any interaction is done with the development server. The `configure_logging` function first finds and imports the logging configurations and then invokes it with the settings. Now `apps.populate` method is called with `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` as an argument. For those who don’t remember `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` is the list in settings.py file where you register all you apps. The `apps.populate` method imports all the app configs and all model modules in those app configs. This is a thread safe method with `RLOCK` as this method can be called by two or more threads running on the server and the `RLOCK` prevents the other threads to reenter this method. The populate method is divided into three phases:

**Phase-1**: Initialize app configs and import app modules. after this it check for any duplicate app names and if found shows `improperly configured` error

**Phase-2**: Import models module of those apps.

**Phase-3**: run the ready function of each app config

After completing all this the control is returned back to the setup function and then to the execute function of the `ManagementUtil`. There is an exception handling mechanism which if for the exceptions raised by the process started by autoreloader to restart the server again. If the runserver command is made with `— noreload` flag then this all is skipped and only `django.setup` function is called.

Now, a method `self.autocomplete` is called. This is a function to suggest the bash commands by taking a space separated string and this doesn’t work when user hasn’t sourced `bash_completion` file (this is checked in environment variables, it it has `DJANGO_AUTO_COMPLETE`). After all this it has conditional statements for different sub commands. If `help` then printing information about help, if `version` the details about version else it executes the following code:

```
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
```

The `fetch_command` function takes the sub command which in our case is `runserver` and a commands dictionary is populated using `get_command` method, which return a dictionary of commands name and callbacks applications. If the sub command is missing due to miss-configured settings file the error is printed. If the command class is previously loaded then it is used otherwise its loaded and the sub command class is returned. Now `run_from_argv` method of that class is called with `self.argv` as arguments. All the command classes are extended from a class `BaseCommand` and the function `run_from_argv` is implemented in that class.

As we step in we create a parser object with the arguments in `argv` at index 1 and 2, those are file location and the command. This internally parses the known arguments and returns parsed arguments. We also get some options and `cmd_options` and now we call `self.execute` method with args and options as parameters. This execute the `execute` from `runserver` class of django. This is an example of run time-polymorphism. This does some checks and calls super class’s (which is `BaseCommand`) `execute` method. This executes the command and perform base checks if needed. This performs normal checks and migration checks if needed and then calls a function called `handle`. This function makes all the checks regarding IP address like checking port, IP address format ipv4 or ipv6. If no address is specified the in takes default address is `address` (i.e. localhost).

Now this calls a `run` function. In the `run` function if `use_reloader` options is true then it calls the `inner_function` else passes the `inner_function` ass argument to `autoreload.main`. In this the passed function is wrapped with the `check_error` decorator and the wrapped function is passed as an argument to `python_reloader` of `autoreload` module. This runs the function related to that command on a different thread. This function is responsible for working of server. After this it calls a method called `reloader_thread()`. As the name itself indicates this function takes care of the reloading mechanism.

Stepping in, the `reloader_thread` calls a method called `ensure_echo_on` which does nothing. Now if a constant `USE_INOTIFY` is true then the change detecting functions is `inotify_code_changed` else it is `code changed`. For me the code detecting function was `code_changed`. Out of curiosity, I searched a little about what I notify is and found out
`Inotify` (inode notify) is a Linux kernel subsystem that acts to extend filesystems to notice changes to the filesystem, and report those changes to applications.

I think as my laptop is windows, I was not able to use `inotify`. So in the function which the windows works with the changes in the files are detected using some timestamps. It stores all the modified timestamps and whenever notices any changes returns `I18N_MODIFIED` value =2 if the changed file ends with `.mo` (extension of a binary file) else returns `FILE_MODIFIED` value =1. If no changes are detected the returns false. If the returned value is `FILE_MODIFIED` then the program is forcefully reloaded and if the returned value is `I18N_MODIFIED` then `reset_translation` method is called. This loop at end has a sleep of 1 sec. So this check happens every one second and hence the django development server automatically reloads when any changes are made to the files.

This is all what happens when the command `python manage.py runserver` is executed. It might be a lengthy process but worth knowing. Next time, when you hit the command you will be having a higher level idea of whats going on.